# Save EllipticEnvelope Model in sklearn in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, tensorflow-lite

I need to save a model that is based on EllipticEnvelope and then convert it to a Tensorflow Lite image to use it on mobile app. Can someone help me how can I store the model?

```
model =  EllipticEnvelope(contamination=outliers_fraction, 
                         #behaviour="new",
                         random_state=RANDOM_SEED, support_fraction=0.7)

model.fit(std_data)
```

I tried something like this:

```
json_model = model.to_json()
open('model_architecture.json', 'w').write(json_model)
```

But I get this error:

> 'EllipticEnvelope' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `EllipticEnvelope` class doesn't have that method. Available method for that class are here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.EllipticEnvelope.html

There is no easy way to save sklearn model into JSON. To do that, you would have to manually write methods to save into JSON and load from JSON.

SKLearn is advising to save model as a pickle or by using Joblib. This is described here:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Here you can read example tutorial how to add JSON dump/load feature into inherited sklearn class:
https://stackabuse.com/scikit-learn-save-and-restore-models/

Although I would discourage you to do that if you can use pickle.

I'm not sure if there is easy way to translate sklearn model into Tensorflow Lite.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.
Yes, I could store and load the models in joblib or pickle formats but there is no straightforward solution to do the conversion of these formats in tensorflow lite converter (it works with .pb models). So I think one possible solution is to find the equivalent `EllipticEnvelope` model in Tensorflow. Is there anything like that? Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @mps, so there is no equivalent. I guess you are trying to solve problem of outlier detection, there is a lot of articles how to achieve that in Keras/Tensorflow https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/02/anomaly-detection-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/ or https://www.kaggle.com/merckel/anomaly-detection-using-tensorflow etc.
However, I don't know the nature of your requirements, but wouldn't be an option for You to just deploy model as an API and do model prediction from mobile via http API? Why you have to deploy model on mobile phone, does it have to work offline?